# removing toolbars from Calendar Webparts

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am new to SharePoint Technology.
I have a out of the box calendar web parts.
When I add it, I get a scroll bar along with it.
Is there any property through which I can remove the scroll bars?

Regards,

Sachin K

Comment: I'm no SharePoint expert, but it looks like the CSS property `overflow: hidden` on the HTML element that has the scroll bar will solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

you have to use CSS or Javascript to do this.

Comment: But... how? This doesn't really answer the question.